# How do I make pip find header files in a specific folder when running in a venv?

Tags: python-venv, pyvenv

I installed Python 3.10.11 from source on my Linux (OpenSuSE Leap 15.4 on AMD64) machine and defined a venv so that I can build an app, which requires a fresh (>= 3.8) Python version. Unfortunately, when getting wxWidgets for Python via pip, I *always* get an error because of a missing header file: `Python.h`:

```
Checking for header Python.h: Distutils not installed? Broken python installation? Get python-config now!
The configuration failed
```

I do have `Python.h` in my Python installation: `/home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/Include`

The `pyvenv.cfg` file looks like this:

```ini
home = /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/bin
implementation = CPython
version_info = 3.10.11.final.0
virtualenv = 20.23.0
include-system-site-packages = false
base-prefix = /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist
base-exec-prefix = /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist
base-executable = /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/bin/python3
```

What I can't find anywhere in the Python docs is how to state a header file folder, just something like `base-include-dir` (if it exists). The `pyvenv.cfg` file is situated in `/home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/displaycal`, whereas the `activate` script lies in `/home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/displaycal/bin` (if this matters).